# Cannot implicit Class A to Generic Type

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, generic-programming

There are multiple projects we are developing on same database.
Lets say project A as namespace **ProjectA** and another project **ProjectB**. When both use DB first the Context will be different but the DbSet are common.
When **ProjectA** create context then Table is **ProjectA.Models.TableA** and **ProjectB** create context then Table is **ProjectB.Models.TableA**

Now, i want to create generic method, to identify a **TableA** and insert **TableA** records.

I have used to identify

```
 string TableName = "TableName";
 Type type = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == TableName);
```

For Generic inserting the records i use below.

```
 public static void Create<TEntity>(this DbContext db, TEntity entityToCreate) where TEntity : class
    {
        db.Set<TEntity>().Add(entityToCreate as TEntity);
    }
```

When i try to insert  **Create(db, item)** where item is an object of tables column and values.

Comment: Can you please clarify what your question is, and the problem you are having? Is what you have above throwing an  throwing an exception, not connecting to the Db, record not updating in the DB, etc?

Comment: Also, seems like your Models should be defined in its own project that ProjectA and ProjectB share. There shouldn't be some database models defined in ProjectA. And then some defined in ProjectB.

Comment: Yes, its throwing the error because it cannot implicit NamespaceA.TableA to NamespaceB.TableA.

Answer (score 0):

The two types are completely different types because they are in different namespaces, even if they have the same names, properties, etc. You can't directly cast between the two.

My suggestion would be to put your models in a separate library (project) and reference that library from `ProjectA`and `ProjectB` You might also put your repository code in that library if it would be the same between the two projects.

Comment: I have the same solution, but is it possible to cast from one class to another class (Another class is generic one).

Comment: You can only downcast to less specific types in the hierarchy, for example a `Cat` to an `Animal`, You cannot (safely) upcast from an `Animal` to a `Cat` or from a `Cat` to a `Toaster` even if they have the same properties (height, color, etc.). They are fundamentally different types.

Answer (score 0):

Here item has same **classA** properties

```
        Type type = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == TableName);
        Object inst = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        foreach (var property in item.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            inst.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name).SetValue(inst, property.GetValue(item, null), null);
        }
        Create(db, inst);
```